# Where can I download facebook-actionscript-api for actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash, facebook

The latest releases of the facebook-actionscript-api caters to actionscript 3.0 does anyone know from where can I downloaded an earlier version which supporsts actionscript 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately There is not an official as2 api for Facebook, but googling aggresively I found this:
http://www.whiteinteractive.com/facebook/asclient.php

... I don't know anything about this library (plus, the project is discontinued the author himself has abandoned it) so by no means I can recommend it. My advice? Upgrade to as3 and you won't look back, it is so much better (and more powerful) than poor old as2!

Comment: googling aggressively, hu? like http://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+actionscript+2.0 , hit #1? :)

Comment: Sadly there is no documentation avalaible for the given api

Answer (score 0):

Only as3 API

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/